# Where was BurÿHaüs near 1663 Breitau?

Tags: germany, church-records, place-names, kurrent

Three people in the 1663 baptism record from Breitau, Germany, in north-eastern Hesse, are listed as being from "BurÿHaüs".  I can find nothing even close to that name in that area.  Can anyone identify where there people were from?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reads like "Breyttauw" to me, so it seems to be a historic spelling of Breitau. The second instance of the name is a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks, guess I was overthinking it.  :D